# Entity Framework writes in the database while doing a read-only operation

Tags: c#, entity-framework, hash, sql-server-ce

In a console application, I have a SQL Server CE database which I am accessing using Entity Framework. Why is the hash value of the `.sdf` database changing after a read only operation?

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string fileName = @" C:\...\bin\Debug\exportedDb.sdf";
        Console.WriteLine("The Hash Before is -->"+ComputeHash(fileName));
        using (var context = new DbaseEntities())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(context.ANNEES.First().ANNEE_UNIVERSITAIRE);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("The Hash After is -->" + ComputeHash(fileName));
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public static string ComputeHash(string fileName)
    {
        var hash = "";

        using (var md5 = MD5.Create())
        {        
            using (var stream = File.OpenRead(fileName))
            {
                hash = BitConverter.ToString(md5.ComputeHash(stream));
            }                                             

            return hash;
        }
    }
}
```

The above code gives returns these results :

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, so far as I'm aware, the database file format isn't documented. There may be database level (meta-)data that is updated whenever the file is opened.

Comment: Any chance to disable those changes? i have a .sdf database that i want to make sure that isn't changing outside of the application, and the hashing seems to be the most appropriate solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the SQL CE engine does sorting and other internal operations, they can be written to temporary tables/objects in the database file.

BUT, you can prevent this from happening by changing your connection string. Add Mode = Read Only to your connection string.

```
Data Source=C:\data\mydb.sdf;Mode=Read Only
```

Comment: thx...so using the hash isn't the best way to make sure that the db hasn't updated from outside my application (i need to Read/Write in the db)